# How can i click on this button with selenium

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can i click on this button with selenium ?

```html
<a class="_42ft _4jy0 rfloat _ohf _4jy4 _517h _51sy" role="button" href="" ajaxify="/nux/wizard/step/?action=skip" rel="async-post" id="u_9_8">İleri</a>
```

Comment: Try to use `click()` method

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, an amazing resource but you should spend some time and [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) the site along with checking [how to ask questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). This will teach you how to best format your question to enable the community to best assist you. By making such poor questions you really are just doing yourself a disservice.

Answer (score 1):

Something I wish I would have figured out earlier was how to create my own advanced CSS selectors here is the page that taught me, it will work in all cases assuming your element is visible in the DOM.

https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/08/taming-advanced-css-selectors/

For your given element you could write this many ways

Generic form 
`tag[attribute='ATTRIBUTE_VALUE']`

For your example

`a[id='u_9_8']`

or

`a[class='_42ft _4jy0 rfloat _ohf _4jy4 _517h _51sy']`

or

`a[rel='async-post']`

Now all these selectors will only be useful if the attribute is unique. But take a look at that article there are many tricks you can use to make CSS selectors work for you.

Answer (score 0):

By using xpath with contains text you can click on the element(below is the answer)

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(text(),'Ileri')]")).click();
```

Try it and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0):

Try any of these below mentioned code.

Using `id` locator

```
driver.findElement(By.id("u_9_8")).click();
```

Using `xpath` locator

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[text()= 'İleri']").click();
```

**Explanation:-** Use `text` method along with `<a>`tag.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@role='button'][text()= 'İleri']").click();
```

**Explanation:-** Use `role` attribute and `text` method along with `<a>` tag.

Comment: Have you try this code? Does my explanation of code helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Please add the wait conditions before you are going to click

Element clicking Via linkText : 
webDriver.findElement(By.linkText("İleri")).click();

Element clicking Via id : 
webDriver.findElement(By.id("u_9_8")).click();

Element clicking Via cssSelector : 
1.webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("._42ft._4jy0.rfloat._ohf._4jy4._517h._51sy")).click();

2.webDriver.findElement(By.cssSelector("a[class='_42ft _4jy0 rfloat _ohf _4jy4 _517h _51sy']")).click();

Element clicking Via javaScript :
        ((JavascriptExecutor) driver).executeScript("arguments[0].click();", webElement);

Here you need to pass the element locator instead of webElement.

Answer (score 0):

We can see ID attribute tag so we can use ID "u_9_8" to click on the button. 
use the below code.

driver.findelement(By.id("u_9_8")).click();

Answer (score -1):

I think you should be able to use the id

driver.findElement(By.id("u_9_8")).click();

Give it a shot